# Extracting a row from data frame with iloc with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

With the following line, I can extract the whole row of a data frame

```
row = df.iloc[1].astype(int)
```

However, I would like to select the second row values when the value of the same column in another row is X. For example, the data frame looks like

```
        V1    V2    V3
M1       1     2     2 
M2       3     7     6
```

Based on the previous line of code, `row=[3,7,6]`. But I want to set a condition on that if the value of the same column for `iloc[0]` is 2. In the end, row should be [7,6]. How can I specify that?

Comment: `df.loc[df.index[1], df.iloc[0]==2]`?

Comment: Or since you are doing type conversion, you don't really need to worry about index chaining: `df.iloc[1].loc[df.iloc[0]==2].astype(int)`.